# How to make the "Final" button in a QWizard not highlighted by default in pyQt/Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I have a QWizard with a page which has a QLayoutForm. There's an edit box in the LayoutForm, in which you can type a description, but you cannot press enter to newline, as that causes the page to advance. Currently I'm overriding a default QWizard with an initialize event which also includes this

```
class MapWizard (QtGui.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MapWizard, self).__init__()
        self.setOption(QtGui.QWizard.NoDefaultButton, True)
        self.addPage(IntroPage())
        self.addPage(SettingsPage())
        self.setWindowTitle("Map Wizard")
        self.show()
```

and if its any help here's the class for the description box

```
class DescriptionBox (QtGui.QLineEdit):
def __init__ (self, parent=None):
    super(DescriptionBox, self).__init__()
    self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
def sizeHint(self):
    return(QtCore.QSize(200,200))
```

However NoDefaultButton doesn't appear to do anything. It doesn't cause an error, but it still doesn't fix my issue with the 'Final' and 'Next' buttons being selected by default, they're focused even when you focus into the lineEditText box.

I'm using PyQt version 4 (Windows), but the solution from Qt should be pretty similar to what I need: to make it so that its possible to press enter in QWizard without advancing

Answer (score 0):

If you use QLineEdit, then Enters are interpreted for advancing the Wizard. Use QTextEdit instead.